# Is there a way to mimic an infinite looping scroll without the page jumping to the top?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm currently working on a website with a masonry grid  – ideally what I'd like to happen is to mimic a looping scroll where when the user reaches the end of the page, the items in the masonry grid repeat from those that were at the top of the page. (Basically, the page doesn't scroll back to the top, the items just repeat.)

Is this possible? And is there a better way of explaining what I'm trying to go after?

I'm currently using script for looping scroll but I'm not quite happy with how the page jumps so abruptly to the top.

I'm just using this right now:

```
 $('document').ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function(){
      if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()) {
        $(document).scrollTop(0);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to the top of your page smoothly, then you can use animate function. then your code will be like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()) {
    var body = $("html, body");
    body.stop().animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1500);
  }
});
```

1500 is the amount in milliseconds to complete the animation.

Comment: I've also created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminur/r2k8c05s/) as example.

Comment: did you check my answer?